# Rotation in Pose mode is wrong/off, rotation x axe

Tags: animation, rigging, bones

I'm trying to recreate this Pose.
[image]

This is what I have so far, but every time when Im trying to use the x axes it rotates in the wrong way.
[image]
[image]

A few more examples pictures[image]
[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]

Its the same for the z axes.
It looks like that every rotation I make is along the y axe. I have no clue why.

Comment: hello, maybe share your file (only the armature if your prefer not to share the character, share the link it will give you): https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: I found the problem. I locked the other axes.